# AS3 type was not found : Sound

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I have this small piece of AS3 code and it doesnt work :(

```
var snd:Sound = new Sound(new URLRequest("Hit1.wav"));
var channel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
channel= snd.play();
```

all I get is

```
type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Sound
type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: SoundChannel
```

how can i fix this?

Canvas

Comment: Are you importing these classes?

Comment: Probably not, but I couldn't find the ones I need on the net. all i have is 

 import flash.display.MovieClip;
 import flash.utils.Timer;
 import flash.events.TimerEvent;
 //
 import flash.events.TouchEvent;

Answer (score 3):

You have to import the classes:

```
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
```

or just:

```
import flash.media.*;
```

Comment: In the livedocs, you'll find all packages an corresponding classes.

Comment: @Canvas you'll have to also import flash.net.URLRequest As Florian said, check the docs to figure out what you have to import, e.g. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html

Comment: import flash.net.URLRequest; If you cant find it on the livedocs.

Comment: Ok i have that now, but now im getting a StreamI/O error, i have imported my Hit1.wav file into the library and in the URLRequest i put "Hit1.wav" but it doesnt like it

Comment: This question is starting to evolve. The question was answered, accept it and ask another if you have a new problem.